# HTTPSConnectionPool Max retries exceeded with url Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connect when running on server,but not on local PC

Tags: python, django, request

When I run this code in the local system, I get an answer easily, but when I put it on the host, I get an error.

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='test.com', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb28512da90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

```
import json
import http.client
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import RegisterForm
from .models import MyUser

def register_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:dashboard'))

    form = RegisterForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        mobile = request.POST.get('mobile')
        user_national = request.POST.get('input-natiionalID')

        try:
            if "mobile" in request.POST:
                user = MyUser.objects.get(mobile=mobile)
                messages.error(request, "شماره موبایل تکراری می باشد و قبلا ثبت شده است")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:register_view'))
                # Send OTP
        except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                try:
                    user = form.save(commit=False)
                    # Send OTP
                    otp = helper.get_random_otp()
                    # helper.send_otp(mobile, otp)
                    # Save OTP
                    za = national_code_check(user_national)
                    user.otp = otp
                    user.code_nationality = request.POST.get('input-natiionalID')
                    user.is_active = False

                    if za == True:
                        # Make an HTTP POST request to the API
                        user_name = "test"
                        password = "test"
                        national_identification_number = user.code_nationality
                        phone_number = user.mobile
                        api_url = "mysite.com"
                        api_port = 8000
                        api_path = "/api1"

                        payload = {
                            'username': user_name,
                            'password': password,
                            'national_mobile': phone_number,
                            'national_identification_number': national_identification_number,
                        }

                        payload_json = json.dumps(payload)

                        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(api_url, api_port)
                        headers = {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        }

                        conn.request("POST", api_path, body=payload_json, headers=headers)

                        response = conn.getresponse()
                        response_data = response.read().decode('utf-8')

                        conn.close()

                        response_json = json.loads(response_data)
                        comment = response_json.get("result", {}).get("data", {}).get("result", {}).get("data", {}).get("comment", "")
                        print("comment: ", comment)
                        if response.status == 200 and comment == "درخواست با موفقیت ثبت شد":
                            # The response is successful, proceed with registration
                            user.save()
                            # Redirect to account:verify
                            request.session['user_mobile'] = user.mobile
                            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:verify'))
                        else:
                            # The response contains an error, show the error message to the user
                            messages.error(request, "کد ملی با تلفن همراه مطابقت ندارد")
                            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:register_view'))

                    else:
                        # The national code is invalid, show an error message to the user
                        messages.error(request, "کد ملی تکراری می باشد و قبلا ثبت شده است")
                        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:register_view'))

                except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
                    messages.error(request, "کد ملی تکراری می باشد و قبلا ثبت شده است")
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:register_view'))
                except Exception as e:
                    messages.error(request, str(e))
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:register_view'))
            else:
                print("user nist- form ha not valid")

    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'form': form}
```

I searched a lot in stackoverflow and also changed the sending method from http to https, but it didn't work